# Twitter bootstrap drown down button with login form (form not staying open)

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, authentication, twitter-bootstrap

I have researched stackoverflow to make a drop-down button with login form stay open when completing the form.  Right now as soon as you try to type, the login form closes.  Here is my code:

```
<div class="top-nav">
<div class="btn-group pull-right dropdown-toggle"> <a class="btn btn-login"  href="#"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Login</a> <a class="btn btn-login dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
<form class="form-horizontal dropdown-menu">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">
        Remember me </label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

At the end of my code just before the body tag I entered this script:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
       $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
       $('.dropdown-menu').find('form').click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Just javascript added isn't keeping the form open.  A solution is greatly appreciated for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue using your code. Removing `.find('form')` from the JavaScript fixed the problem.